# Unable to update the sequence on delete

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE dbo.ControlBrandMapping
SET Sequence = SUBQUERY.SORTORDER
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Sequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sequence) AS SORTORDER 
     FROM ControlBrandMapping) SUBQUERY
WHERE ControlBrandMapping.Sequence = SUBQUERY.Sequence`
```

What I am trying to do here is on delete I am trying to update the sequence of rows.
On the user screen I have a tabelDnD which on drag rearranges the sequence.

Lets say the order was:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Lets say now I deleted row #3. I want 4 to become 3, and 5 to become 4.

I.e.

```
1
2
3
4
```

It's giving me weird set of sequence. But at the same time when I read just the row using tabelDnD again it becomes alright. I believe there is some problem with the query that I have mentioned above.

Note: it's not an `IDENTITY` column. And its not the only column in my table.

Please help with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you need to renumber all of the subsequent rows?  This sounds like a presentation issue, i.e. you want to display a tidy list of numbers to a human.  That doesn't require storing the "pretty" numbers in the database.

That said, you can use something like this to handle a single deletion:

```
 update dbo.ControlBrandMapping
   set Sequence = Sequence - 1
   where Sequence > @DeletedSequence
```

This sort of thing tends to unravel in a typical system that has multiple users updating the database at the same time.  Typical systems also have foreign references that would need to be updated and so on ... .

Comment: Thanks for this. I will update you whether this works once i get back on my desk.